# Is it possible to create subversion repo inside a subversion working copy

Tags: svn

Is it possible to do subversion like baby doll to create intermediairy versioning hierarchically ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) in a subversion repository. An external is a link to a different repository and (optionally) a specific revision of it.

> Sometimes it is useful to construct a working copy that is made out of a number of different checkouts. For example, you may want different subdirectories to come from different locations in a repository, or perhaps from different repositories altogether. You could certainly setup such a scenario by hand—using svn checkout to create the sort of nested working copy structure you are trying to achieve. But if this layout is important for everyone who uses your repository, every other user will need to perform the same checkout operations that you did.